# What's the nicest most-pythonic way to select rows in pandas for datetime conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Filtering rows for `Scalar` and `Logical` conditions are quite well-known and reported here, e.g. `df[df['col']>=0]` can be used to filter the negative rows out. Yet, I've come to work with datetime and wonder what ways work, I might answer with approaches I find or try out myself.

Comment: Have you tried the same way, like `df1[df1['date'] < '12/09/2022 12:12:00']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas, as long as you have all of your datetime data formatted as datetime, it behaves very similiarly. Here are some examples and an additional link to reference.

Filter row row between two dates.

```
df[(df['date'] > '2019-12-01') & (df['date'] < '2019-12-31')]
```

Filter rows by index

```
df2.loc['2019-12-01':'2019-12-31']
```

[https://datascientyst.com/filter-by-date-pandas-dataframe/#:~:text=Here%20are%20several%20approaches%20to%20filter%20rows%20in,3%29%20Filter%20rows%20by%20date%20with%20Pandas%20query](https://datascientyst.com/filter-by-date-pandas-dataframe/#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20several%20approaches%20to%20filter%20rows%20in,3%29%20Filter%20rows%20by%20date%20with%20Pandas%20query)

Comment: Actually, I thought your approach used datetime objects not datetime string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer by `Omnishroom`, if your column in your dataframe, `df`, is already a `datetime` type, you would have no problem using what he mentioned. But if your column is a `string` like mine, then use `.dt.date` as follows:

```
series[series['date_column'].dt.date == datetime.date(2007, 1, 1)]
```

Refer to `Omnishroom` for more. I've just added `.dt.date`. Also, since my datetime strings were in another format, I didn't use that type of approach.